# How do I print a window (or screen) by using PrintDialog (or equivalent)?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print the main window to both a printer and file (through the use of PrintDialog). I have tried the following three solutions, but there are some problems with each of them (explained below). Does anyone know of a good solution, or perhaps improve on the existing ones?

1.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df305a6c-4546-4665-a9fb-1b190ea47ec6/how-to-print-bitmapsource?forum=wpf

This solution cuts the final document/print, so that not the whole screen is displayed.

```
private void PrintBitmapSource(BitmapSource inBms)
{
    var pd = new PrintDialog();
    var ret = pd.ShowDialog();
    if (ret.Value)
    {
        var dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawImage(inBms, new Rect(0, 0, inBms.Width, inBms.Height));
        }
        pd.PrintVisual(dv, "document image");
    }
}
```

2. http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66#.VcMld_ntlBc

This solution creates a full print, but has some strange artifacts, where it seems to mix elements from before and after resize. Also resizes the screen.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    //get selected printer capabilities
    System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

    //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
 double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                this.ActualHeight);

    //Transform the Visual to scale
    this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

    //get the size of the printer page
    Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

    //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
    this.Measure(sz);
    this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

    //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
    printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "First Fit to Page WPF Print"); 
}
```

3.
Setting PageMediaSize to the screen resolution (hard-coded for testing purposes).

This solution is almost perfect, but has an area to the right that is black, but some elements are displayed correctly on top of this black area. It may seem like the black area starts where the solution #1 cuts off.

```
var pd = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
var ret = pd.ShowDialog();
if (ret.Value)
{
    pd.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(1920, 1080);
    pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
    pd.PrintVisual(ApplicationGlobal.MainWindow as Window, "testprint");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of saving a control inheriting from FrameworkElement to a bitmap image file using `RenderTargetBitmap`:

```
private void SaveFrameworkElementToBitmap(FrameworkElement gridinput, string filepath)
{
    gridinput.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    int grid1Width = (int)Math.Round(gridinput.ActualWidth);
    int grid1Height = (int)Math.Round(gridinput.ActualHeight);
    grid1Width = grid1Width == 0 ? 1 : grid1Width;
    grid1Height = grid1Height == 0 ? 1 : grid1Height;

    RenderTargetBitmap rtbmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(grid1Width, grid1Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
    rtbmp.Render(gridinput);
    BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtbmp));
    FileStream gridbmpfilestrm = File.Create(filepath);
    encoder.Save(gridbmpfilestrm);
    gridbmpfilestrm.Close();
    rtbmp.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to print the image to a printer, by using the PrintDialog (or equivalent). Edited title to avoid confusion.

Comment: It shows a different way of rendering the visual, which you could then use to print. Your problem is likely due to using PrintDialog.PrintVisual. You could try rendering using RenderTargetBitmap and then printing the rendered bitmap.

Comment: What exactly should I input to the printDialog.PrintVisual() method?

Comment: Nothing. You would no longer be using the PrintDialog to print a Visual, You would be printing a rendered bitmap instead.

Comment: OK, does this mean that I am unable to print to a printer using this solution?

Comment: No you can still print to a printer, but instead of using PrintVisual you would create a FlowDocument or XPS and use the PrintDocument method to print it. I don't have the time to build you a complete sample, but this will provide all the answers you need: [WPF Printing Overview](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Printing-Overview-f28c541a)

Comment: Ah, OK I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a method that can print FrameworkElement. You will need to set the *Allow unsafe code* property on the project.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public void Print(FrameworkElement objectToPrint)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities =
            printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
        double dpiScale = 300.0 / 96.0;
        FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
        try
        {
            // Change the layout of the UI Control to match the width of the printer page
            objectToPrint.Width = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth;
            objectToPrint.UpdateLayout();
            objectToPrint.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            Size size = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, objectToPrint.DesiredSize.Height);
            objectToPrint.Measure(size);
            size = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, objectToPrint.DesiredSize.Height);
            objectToPrint.Measure(size);
            objectToPrint.Arrange(new Rect(size));

            // Convert the UI control into a bitmap at 300 dpi
            double dpiX = 300;
            double dpiY = 300;
            RenderTargetBitmap bmp =
                new RenderTargetBitmap(
                    Convert.ToInt32(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth * dpiScale),
                    Convert.ToInt32(objectToPrint.ActualHeight * dpiScale),
                    dpiX,
                    dpiY,
                    PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bmp.Render(objectToPrint);

            // Convert the RenderTargetBitmap into a bitmap we can more readily use
            PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp2;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                png.Save(memoryStream);
                bmp2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memoryStream);
            }
            document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(
                printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth,
                printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);

            // break the bitmap down into pages
            int pageBreak = 0;
            int previousPageBreak = 0;
            int pageHeight = Convert.ToInt32(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight * dpiScale);
            while (pageBreak < bmp2.Height - pageHeight)
            {
                pageBreak += pageHeight; // Where we thing the end of the page should be

                // Keep moving up a row until we find a good place to break the page
                while (!IsRowGoodBreakingPoint(bmp2, pageBreak)) pageBreak--;

                PageContent pageContent = this.GeneratePageContent(
                    bmp2,
                    previousPageBreak,
                    pageBreak,
                    document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width,
                    document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height,
                    capabilities);
                document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
                previousPageBreak = pageBreak;
            }

            // Last Page
            PageContent lastPageContent = this.GeneratePageContent(
                bmp2,
                previousPageBreak,
                bmp2.Height,
                document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width,
                document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height,
                capabilities);
            document.Pages.Add(lastPageContent);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Scale UI control back to the original so we don't effect what is on the screen 
            objectToPrint.Width = double.NaN;
            objectToPrint.UpdateLayout();
            objectToPrint.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
            Size size = new Size(
                capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth,
                capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
            objectToPrint.Measure(size);
            objectToPrint.Arrange(
                new Rect(
                    new Point(
                        capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,
                        capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight),
                    size));
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        }
        printDialog.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Print Document Name");
    }
}

private PageContent GeneratePageContent(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int top,
    int bottom, double pageWidth, double PageHeight,
    System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities)
{
    FixedPage printDocumentPage = new FixedPage();
    printDocumentPage.Width = pageWidth;
    printDocumentPage.Height = PageHeight;

    int newImageHeight = bottom - top;
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpPage = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, top,
            bmp.Width, newImageHeight), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Create a new bitmap for the contents of this page
    Image pageImage = new Image();
    BitmapSource bmpSource =
        System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            bmpPage.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmp.Width, newImageHeight));

    pageImage.Source = bmpSource;
    pageImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

    // Place the bitmap on the page
    printDocumentPage.Children.Add(pageImage);

    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(printDocumentPage);

    FixedPage.SetLeft(pageImage, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
    FixedPage.SetTop(pageImage, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);

    pageImage.Width = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth;
    pageImage.Height = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight;
    return pageContent;
}

private bool IsRowGoodBreakingPoint(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int row)
{
    double maxDeviationForEmptyLine = 1627500;
    bool goodBreakingPoint = false;

    if (rowPixelDeviation(bmp, row) < maxDeviationForEmptyLine)
        goodBreakingPoint = true;

    return goodBreakingPoint;
}

private double rowPixelDeviation(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int row)
{
    int count = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double totalVariance = 0;
    double standardDeviation = 0;
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmp.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            bmp.PixelFormat);
    int stride = bmpData.Stride;
    IntPtr firstPixelInImage = bmpData.Scan0;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* p = (byte*)(void*)firstPixelInImage;
        p += stride * row; // find starting pixel of the specified row
        for (int column = 0; column < bmp.Width; column++)
        {
            count++; //count the pixels

            byte blue = p[0];
            byte green = p[1];
            byte red = p[3];

            int pixelValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, red, green, blue).ToArgb();
            total += pixelValue;
            double average = total / count;
            totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - average, 2);
            standardDeviation = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);

            // go to next pixel
            p += 3;
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return standardDeviation;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, is there a way to shorten it? I suppose some of the Command-related code can be omitted, as the print is in my case triggered by a key press.

Comment: I've removed the command. Everything else is required for it to work properly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried to use it, but I still receive some issues similar to solution #2.